# Delete characters from spannable CharSequence

Tags: android

I have the following input data in String: "Hello #this# is #sample# text."

It sets background color for all elements between # characters. Here's what I got so far:

```
public static CharSequence colorBackground(CharSequence text) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#");

    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString( text );
    if( pattern != null )
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( text );
        while( matcher.find() )
        {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
            CharacterStyle span = new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF404040);
            spannable.setSpan( span, start, end, 0 );
        }
    }
    return spannable;
}
```

Setting background color works, but placeholder characters # are styled too. How to remove them before returning result, because method ReplaceAll doesn't exist for CharSequence?

I use this function to style TextView rows in ListView. It feels a bit slower in emulator after adding this styling function. Maybe I should approach it in some other way e.g. use a custom TextView with custom draw function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounded like a fun thing to try to figure out.

The key was [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html). With SpannableString the text itself is immutable, but with SpannableStringBuilder both the text and the markup can be changed. With that in mind I modified your snippet a little to do what you want:

```
public static CharSequence colorBackground(CharSequence text) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#");

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder( text );

    if( pattern != null )
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( text );
        int matchesSoFar = 0;
        while( matcher.find() )
        {
            int start = matcher.start() - (matchesSoFar * 2);
            int end = matcher.end() - (matchesSoFar * 2);
            CharacterStyle span = new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF404040);
            ssb.setSpan( span, start + 1, end - 1, 0 );
            ssb.delete(start, start + 1);
            ssb.delete(end - 2, end -1);
            matchesSoFar++;
        }
    }
    return ssb;
}
```

I don't have much experience with Spannables in general, and I don't know if the way I've gone about deleting the "#" is the best method, but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Spannables are a bit confusing to work with at start. At least it works faster than fromHtml.

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove them before returning result, because method ReplaceAll doesn't exist for CharSequence?

You could take the approach of [`Html.fromHtml()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) -- build the `SpannedString`, don't try modifying it in place.